# Poor Render of Google Font In Blog Post

Tags: bug, blog

While perusing the most recent SO [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/10/03/mapping-ecosystems-software-development), I noticed that the Miriam Libre font used for the Related Articles heading is being poorly rendered by the browser. Please see screen captures below illustrating the issue (may require fullscreen size to notice the errant spurs).

With Google Chrome 61.0.3163:
[image: chrome screencap]

With Mozilla Firefox 55.0.3:
[image: firefox screencap]

OS is 64-bit Windows 7 Pro SP1

I checked the Google Font page for [Miriam Libre](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Miriam+Libre) and it rendered fine there.

By no means a show-stopper, the text is still completely legible, just a bit ugly, but I thought it may be something your team wants to look into.

Comment: *may require fullscreen* ... and a pair of glasses...

Comment: @rene click the screenshots ;)

Comment: The lowercase r is hinted pretty awful, guess that's what it is about.  These companies are too well funded for their employees to ever see that.  4K monitors for everybody, yay.

Comment: I don't see it, can we please have some red circles? They look the same to me.

Comment: @ivarni do you not see the little stumps at the top of most letters? It's especially visible with the letter 'o'.

Comment: @Stijn Oh wow, I really did need a pair of glasses

Comment: Repro'd on the latest Chrome here.

Comment: No repro on Win 8.1 Pro x64 latest Chrome

Comment: @kayess: There are no  little stumps at the top of most letters? It's a tiny detail...

Comment: Repro on Opera 48.0.2685.16/Chromium 61.0.3163.71 Windows 10 x64

Comment: Renders fine for me on Chrome 60.0.3112.90 & 61.0.3163.100 on Windows 10 x64 and Chromium 61.0.3163.100 (dev build) on Debian 9.1 x64.

Comment: @Cerbrus it's fine at any browser zoom levels, _but_ using the Windows built-in magnifier it gets visible at 200%. So it's repro'd.

Comment: @kayess: Funny enough, I can't repro this on any zoom level greater than 100%. (Smaller is just indistinguishable)

Comment: Could not reproduce it here. Font is being displayed finely in Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) at Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: A similar issue I have with Chrome on Windows 7 Pro 64 is that it occasionally will lose font smoothing (or something) and all of its fonts will become terrible looking. This is not specific to stackoverflow though. It's also a *lot* more noticeable than what you've posted.

Comment: They are supposed to be fractals. (*It's a feature, not a bug.*)

Comment: @NisargShah Then why are they not apparent on any of glyph images on Google Font page? (You did actually look at the font page before just declaring something as a fact, right?)

Comment: @user3351605 I'm just being optimistic. :P

Comment: @NisargShah Appears your sarcasm went over my head :)

Comment: No repro for me. macOS Sierra (10.12.6), recent Chrome (61.0.3163.100 64-bit).

Comment: Interesting is that the page kills my rendering process in Chrome Dev Tools (f12)

Comment: _Safari Firefox?_

Comment: @SeinopSys Oops, fixed, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Repro in Firefox 58 x64 on Windows 10 v1703, both on the blog post **and** on Google Fonts — you just need to drag the size slider down to 18px, then you will see the awful. Basically I think the font is broken.